# Подмена иконки приложения

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-10

При инсталляции приложения, в меню Пуск (Start Menu\Programs) создаётся ярил на исполняемый файл приложения.
В приложении несколько экранов, и на каждый экран устанавливается своя иконка, её можно видеть в панели задач, когда приложение запущено. Проблема в том, что при наличии ярлыка в меню пуск, он переопределяет все эти иконки. Смена иконок уже не происходит.
Данный эффект наблюдался и на других приложениях в Window 10. Даже если его приложение запускать через exe.
Каким образом можно решить эту проблему(кроме как отказаться от создания ярлыка)?